# Doxygen not generating documentation for inherited template class C#

Tags: c#, templates, documentation, doxygen, code-documentation

I have a class declared as follows:

```
public class RoutingPair<R> where R: class
```

Which has documentation (triple-slash). Now, I also have another class with the same name that extends this class, except it takes an extra template argument:

```
public class RoutingPair<R, T> : RoutingPair<R> where R: class where T : class
```

This is so it reuses the functionality of the `RoutingPair<R>` class since the latter merely extends functionality for listening on another interface. This is also documented with triple-slash.

When I go to generate my documentation in Doxygen, Doxygen only generates documentation for the `RoutingPair<R>` class, not the `RoutingPair<R,T>` class. Is there any way to get it to do this?

Comment: Have you tried adding `/// <inheritdoc />` to the derived class?

Comment: Just tried it now, did not change the output. However I did notice something strange: it's generating documentation for two RoutingPair classes, however they both link to RoutingPair<R>.

Comment: Please specify the used doxygen version (when not the current version 1.8.14) please try this one as well. Please add a small example showing the problem and the settings used in the doxygen configuration file (Doxyfile) that are non standard.

Comment: Hello, I upgraded to 1.8.14 and still have the problem. I have no non-standard settings beyond the dot filepath and output for .chm. I also believe I've given enough details to reconstruct the problem: Create a class `Class<R>` and then another, `Class<R,T> : Class<R>`.

Comment: Might have to do with the 'where', please create an example to create the small example.